# loop thru array for each item

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops

My ScheduleType_ID is stored in a database like this: 1~2~3~ etc.
I need to be able to access each number (always from 0-9) so that i can do something on a WinForm.  There is a checkedlistbox control and these numbers represent which selection need to be checked.  The code I have below isn't quite getting me there.

```
 While myReader.Read
     If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(myReader("SchType_ID").ToString) Then
     SchedArray = (myReader("SchType_ID").ToString).Split("~")
         For i = 0 To SchedArray.Length - 2
            builder.Append(SchedArray(i) & ",")
         Next
     End If
 End While
```

Answer (score 1):

**This should do it for you without an array...**

```
 Dim intcount As Integer = 0 'Used to make sure commas are in order
 For Each item As Integer In myReader("SchType_ID").ToString.Split("~")
    If intcount >= 1 Then
      builder.Append(",")
      builder.Append(item.ToString)
    Else
      builder.Append(item.ToString)
      intcount += 1
    End If
 Next
```

**Another example adding the items to an array**

```
 Dim strArray As New List(Of Integer)
 Dim intcount As Integer = 0 'Used to make sure commas are in order

    'Add items to the array
    For Each item As Integer In myReader("SchType_ID").ToString.Split("~")
        strArray.Add(item)
    Next

    'Add each item to the string builder
    For Each intItem As Integer In strArray
        If intcount >= 1 Then
            builder.Append(",")
            builder.Append(intItem.ToString)
        Else
            builder.Append(intItem.ToString)
            intcount += 1
        End If
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString) 'Only for testing purposes
```

**Here's a function for you as well**

```
 Public Function BuildArray(ByVal strItems As String) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim lstArray As New List(Of Integer)

    For Each item As Integer In strItems.Split("~")
        lstArray.Add(item)
    Next

    Return lstArray
 End Function
```

*To use the function, you can use it this way...

```
    Dim lstArray As List(Of Integer)
    Dim intcount As Integer = 0

    lstArray = New List(Of Integer)(BuildArray(myReader("SchType_ID").ToString))

    'Add each item to the string builder
    For Each intItem As Integer In lstArray
        If intcount >= 1 Then
            builder.Append(",")
            builder.Append(intItem.ToString)
        Else
            builder.Append(intItem.ToString)
            intcount += 1
        End If
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString) 'Testing purpose only
```

Happy Coding!